# Slider width and height without stretching

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I'm working on a website for a friend of mine. There's only one problem. The slider won't fit in the frame without stretching.

I've set it to 100% height, but it won't work out. (Its also responsive)
I want it to be a nice image in the original width and height (100x100, 200x200 etc) without stretching (200x500).

I hope you guys can help me out on this.
I'd tried alot and also asked some other people but they can't help me with this.

You can see the slider over here.
http://tinyurl.com/p36hz6u

Here's another version of the slider, but on this version the slider image gets cut off
http://tinyurl.com/nfjjvwu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images are background images, consider using the `background-size:contain;` which will allow the image to grow as large as visible/possible without stretching, and then you can position the background image wherever desired with `background-position`

If the slides have actual physical `<img />` tags, I made a JSfiddle that demonstrates code that will contain an image within an element. In this example, the `<div>` tags represent a browser window and can be resized: http://jsfiddle.net/dds27w2y/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly what I would do is to remove the: `background-size: 100% 100%` and add a `background-position: center center`.
Then I would add a `background-color: white` to the container. This would make it look nicer and it would be centered.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, I used your lines combined with Brian's ones and it worked out. Thanks